# Increase font size at button click

Tags: jquery, css

I  have a table  and in the end there is a button, when click on button text size in the rows of the table should be double in size. Sorry I am new to JQuery so my question seems to be silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your page has only one table then try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("tr").css("font-size","200%");
  });
});
```

Here `tr` is the table row and 200% means double text size